# Google Map keeps re-rendering even if render() is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, redux

I'm currently importing google map to my project using reactjs and redux.

But whenever I click on the marker or just zoom in, the whole map gets rerender 
 and the map goes gray and re-draws the same map with the same marker.

I've tried using shouldComponentUpdate, and it successfully stops the render() function being called, but the map is still rerendering!

The eventlistener of marker when clicked

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ()=>{
  this.props.dispatch(Map.showChatroom(id, title));
});
```

shouldComponentUpdate:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(this.props.map.location.lat === nextProps.map.location.lat){
      return false
    }else{
      return true
    }
  }
```

render():

```
  render() {
    const {map} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          map.activeChatroom.id != null &&
            <Chatroom id={map.activeChatroom.id} title={map.activeChatroom.title} />
        }
        <GoogleMap map={map} getPostion={this.getPostion.bind(this)}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

GoogleMap:

```
const GoogleMap = function(props){
  return (
        <div className="map">
          <div className='map__state'>
              Zoom level: {props.map.map.zoom}<br />
              Map type: {props.map.map.maptype}<br />
              Latitude: {props.map.location.lat}<br />
              Longtitude: {props.map.location.lng}<br />
              Place: {props.map.location.place_formatted}<br />
              Place ID: {props.map.location.place_id}<br />
              Location: {props.map.location.place_location}<br />
              <button className="map__state__positioningBtn" onClick={props.getPostion}>Positioning</button>
          </div>
          <input className='pac_input' type='text' placeholder='Enter a location' />
          <div className='map__container' />;

        </div>
        );
}
```

And the map__container class is where the google map is rendered at

Demo: https://hello-neighbor.github.io/Hello-Neighbor-Chat/

Source Code: https://github.com/Hello-Neighbor/Hello-Neighbor-Chat

I'll really appreciate any answers or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs `shouldComponentUpdate` doesn't prevent re-rendering of child components (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

> Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes.
>
> Currently, if shouldComponentUpdate() returns false, then componentWillUpdate(), render(), and componentDidUpdate() will not be invoked. Note that in the future React may treat shouldComponentUpdate() as a hint rather than a strict directive, and returning false may still result in a re-rendering of the component.

See here how to better organize your code for the Google Maps: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/.

Hope it will helps.